# Missing numpy lib when trying to install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have numpy install as shown. I'm using the instructions for the M1 chip
https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

```
(base) cody@Codys-MBP ~ % pip install numpy --upgrade --force-reinstall
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.23.5-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (13.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.23.5
    Uninstalling numpy-1.23.5:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.23.5
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.9 are installed in '/Users/cody/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed numpy-1.23.5
(base) cody@Codys-MBP ~ % python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf;"
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

Comment: It might be because the version of NumPy you have installed is not compatible with the version of TensorFlow you are using. Try uninstalling and then reinstalling TensorFlow and NumPy with the following commands `pip uninstall tensorflow numpy` and then `pip install tensorflow numpy`.

Comment: Remove the whole miniconda directory and follow the instructions again. Do not install Numpy manually.

Answer (score 0):

It was a numpy version issue. I uninstalled everything , then let tensor flow resolve its dependency.